# Pass R-Value array in C

Tags: arrays, c, implicit-conversion, rvalue

If we consider the function

```
int sum(int* nums, size_t len)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) sum += nums[i];
    return sum;
}
```

We could call it using an lvalue as such

```
int[] nums = {1,2,3};
sum(nums, 3);
```

But when trying to use an rvalue it doesn't work.

```
sum({1,2,3}, 3);
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: you have a return statement in a void function. Either remove the retrurn or make the sum function's return type `int`

Comment: You are completely right, sorry, i didn't pay that much attention to the example since that was not the focus but will fix it up rn

Comment: It doesn't work anyway, because your `sum` function returns `void`. But you could use [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal): `sum((int[]){1,2,3}, 3);`. You could even wrap `sum` in a macro that automatically determines the length of the array. Or you could just write `1 + 2 + 3`. (I think that what you want is not a frequent use case in C.)

Comment: Well of course this is a minimal example, I actually want to process a char**

Comment: Fair enough. I can imagine something like `key_in(str, {"red", "green", "blue", NULL})`.

Comment: Well, as I stated in my question, such an approach doesn't work, giving the error "no instance of overloaded function .... arument types are ({...},  int), and compound literals don't work with the IDE

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There may be other options.

Comment: Okay, we have a `static const char*` and we want to create that from a set of other `const char *`s. So we have a function taking in a `const char *[]` and the size of that array to return the value.

Comment: Hm, and you concatenate them? Or just determine the sum of their lengths? I don't really see the need to include the string array in the function call verbatim. (C can do a lot of things, but it is not as terse as newer languages.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [*compound literal*](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5) (which is available in C99 or later) and pass it directly:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int* nums, size_t len)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) sum += nums[i];
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int rc = sum((int []){1,2,3}, 3);
    printf("%d\n", rc);
}
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c18 -pedantic t.c
$ ./a.out 
6
```

The lifetime of the compound literal is its enclosing *block* - in this case, it's the `main` function.

Comment: interestingly enough this gives me a "cast to incomplete array type “int []” is not allowed" error

Comment: What's your compiler and does it support C99? How are you compiling (command/options)?

Comment: I am just using plain VS. The IDE tells me the aforementioned error, while at build I receive "a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax"

Comment: MS doesn't support all the C features. I suspect C99's compound literals is one of them.

Comment: Hmm, strange. So basically I wanted to create a static const from a function that receives an array. Do you see any other way of doing so given compound literals are not an option?